# If B is symmetric, is A * B * A' = A * A' * B?

Tags: linear-algebra, symmetric-matrices

If matrix $B$ is symmetric (positive definite) of size $nxn$ and Matrix $A$ is also $nxn$. Is it the case that $A \times B \times A' = A \times A' \times B$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no reason. The matrix $A$ does not play any role in your question. Take the identity matrix. Then

$$\pmatrix{1 & 2 \cr 2 & 1} \pmatrix{1 & 1 \cr 0 & 1} = \pmatrix{1 & 3 \cr 2 & 3}$$

$$\pmatrix{1 & 1 \cr 0 & 1}\pmatrix{1 & 2 \cr 2 & 1}  = \pmatrix{3 & 3 \cr 2 & 1}$$